# C/C++ library for lazy evaluation of SIMD/SSE expressions

Tags: c++, sse, intel-mkl, parse-tree

Libraries such as intel-`MKL` or amd-`ACML` provide easier interface to SIMD operations on vectors, but I want to chain several functions together. Are there readily available libraries where I can register a parse tree for an expression like

```
log( tanh(x) + exp(x) )
```

and then evaluate it on all members of an array ? What I want to avoid is to make a temporary arrays of `tanh(x)`, `exp(x)` and `tanh(x) + exp(x)`  by calling the mkl or acml functions for `tanh()`, `exp()` and `+`.

I can unroll the loop by hand and use the sse instructions directly, but was wondering if there are C++ libraries which does this for you, i.e.

```
1. Handles SIMD/SSE functions  
2. Allows building of parse trees out of SIMD/SSE functions.
```

I am very much a newbie and have never used SSE or MKL/ACML before, just venturing out into new territory.

Comment: @VJo thanks for fixing the typos and reformatting the numbered list.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent *snort, snort, ahem* but Wolfram Alpha has some optimization and simplification tools like `simplify log( tanh(x) + exp(x) )`] and they have an API too.  Might be useful to some aspect of what you're doing, or not: http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2011/04/25/algebraic-simplification-simplifying-expressions-in-wolframalpha/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not do *exactly* what you want, but I suggest you take a look at [macstl](http://www.pixelglow.com/macstl/). It's a SIMD valarray implementation which uses template metaprogramming, and which can combine expressions into a single loop. You may be able to use this *as is* or perhaps as a basis for something closer to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Intel ABB](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-array-building-blocks/). It uses a just in time compilation approach IIRC. It can use vector instructions and multithreading depending on the sizes of the vectors you act upon.

Comment: Thanks I will look it up. But I think I cannot release the code under GPL.